# Pause and resume an observable based on a boolean gate in RxJava 2.X?

Tags: android, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

Let's say I have a Processor that emits a boolean value when ever a button is pressed, think of this as a toggle.

```
    boolean gateValue = true;
    PublishProcessor<Boolean> gate = PublishProcessor.create();
    view.onButtonClicked()
            .subscribe(new Action1<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void call(final Void aVoid) {
                    gate.onNext(gateValue = !gateValue);
                }
            }));
```

What I would like to do is use the value of the gate to pause and resume an observable sequence, buffering the emitted values whilst paused.

I've read into this a lot and while it seems possible in reactive extensions for other languages, RxJava doesn't seem to support it.

Here's an example of what I'd like to achieve, it simply outputs an incremental value every second. When I press the button I want the output to stop until I press it again which should output every item emitted between the two button presses:

```
Flowable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .bufferWhile(gate)
                .flatMapIterable(longs -> longs)
                .subscribe(new Consumer<Long>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(final Long aLong) throws Exception {
                        view.displayTime(aLong);
                    }
                });
```

Does anyone know of a way to achieve something like this?

**Edit** I've written a blog post on how to achieve this https://medium.com/@scottalancooper/pausing-and-resuming-a-stream-in-rxjava-988a0977b771#.gj7fsi1xk

Comment: This requires a custom operator and I have a possible implementation for RxJava 1 [here](https://gist.github.com/akarnokd/1c54e5a4f64f9b1e46bdcf62b4222f08).

Comment: @akarnokd Do you know enough about RxJava 2 to know if I can easy convert it? I've read that creating custom operators is tricky so I don't think I'm at that level yet

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is now an operator `valve()` in the RxJava2Extensions library that does the requested behavior.

Comment: It's amazing what you can accomplish when you hook it with Android's lifecycle.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using default RxJava operators:

```
    final Random random = new Random();
    final Observable<Boolean> gates = Observable.interval(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .map(it -> random.nextBoolean())
            .startWith(false)
            .doOnNext(it -> System.out.println("Gate " + (it ? "opened" : "closed")))
            .take(100);
    final Observable<Long> data = Observable.interval(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .doOnNext(it -> System.out.println("New value " + it))
            .take(100);

    gates.publish(innerGates -> data.publish(innerData -> Observable.merge(
            innerData.window(
                    innerGates.distinctUntilChanged().filter(it -> it),
                    (ignore -> innerGates.distinctUntilChanged().filter(it -> !it))
            ).flatMap(it -> it),
            innerData.buffer(
                    innerGates.distinctUntilChanged().filter(it -> !it),
                    (ignore -> innerGates.distinctUntilChanged().filter(it -> it))
            )
                    .flatMap(Observable::from)
    )))
            .subscribe(it -> System.out.println("On next " + it));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the ready-made `Observable.window` operator that takes one `Observable<T>` parameter.

Comment: Wouldn't that only emit from the source observable when the gate observable emits? I want the source to emit until the gate emits a false.

Comment: Ah, indeed - you could use the 2-parameter to open and close on the `true`/`false being emitted.

Comment: That works if I tell it to open when there's a true value and close when there's a false but it doesn't buffer the emitted items when the window is closed, it just drops them. I've also just realised that both buffer and window only emit items in batches rather than a stream so neither operators are going to work.